# how to return result from model to controller in nodejs

Tags: node.js, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm working on node js for the first time.My nodejs project is in MVC style and I am doing Ajax request for login.but i'm not getting data from the model...
Here is the code....

Controller / Auth.js

```
  var data = req.body;
  Auth_model.login(data, function(err,result){
    if(!result){
        response = {
          error:true,
          message : "Username or Password is wrong."
        };
        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));
      }else{
        response = {
          error:false,
          message : "Logged in Successfully."
        };
        // console.log(result);
        res.send(JSON.stringify(response));   
      }
  });
});
```

Model / Auth_model.js

```
module.exports.login = function(data, callback){
  var email = data.email;
  var password  = data.password;
  var sql = 'SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email='+mysql.escape(email);
  db.query(sql, callback,function (err, result, fields) {
    if (result) {
      bcrypt.compare(password,result[0].password, function(err, result) {
            if(result){
              return result;
            }else{
              return err;
            }
      });
    }
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Controller / Auth.js

```
  var data = req.body;

   // here you are passing your callback function as second argument 
   // So, you can use it in your login model when you get your response 

  Auth_model.login(data, function(err,result){ 
   ......... 
  }
```

Model / Auth_model.js

```
module.exports.login = function(data, callback){
    .......
            if(result){
              // use your callback function pass error : null and result:result
              callback(null,result);
            }else{
             callback(err,null)
            }
    ......
}
```

You can use promise as well instead of callback function like

```
module.exports.login = (data) =  new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   .......
            if(result){
              // use your callback function pass error : null and result:result
              resolve(result);
            }else{
             reject(err);
            }
    ......
});

// use it like  : 

 login(data).then(result=>console.log(result)).catch(err=>console.log(err))
```

Learn more and more about callback function and promises.

Answer (score 0):

as I see that you are passing a callback function within the login function but inside the function definition of login function you are not calling the callback and passing the data to it.

You would have to do something like this.

```
module.exports.login = function(data, callback) {
  var email = data.email;
  var password = data.password;
  var sql = "SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE email=" + mysql.escape(email);
  db.query(sql, callback, function(err, result, fields) {
    if (result) {
      bcrypt.compare(password, result[0].password, function(err, result) {
        if (result) {
          return callback(null, result);
        } else {
          return callback(err, null);
        }
      });
    }
  });
};
```